# Import external javascript library in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, spreedly

I've looked through several questions about importing javascript libraries in a React Native application, but they do not seem to apply to my case.  What I'm trying to do is import a javascript library, preferably via a URL and not a local JS file, that I can use in an RN app - basically, I'm looking for an RN equivalent of `<script src="https://some/url/to/a/library.min.js"></script>`.

Specifically, the library I'm trying to use is Spreedly, which can be referenced using the URL "https://core.spreedly.com/iframe/iframe-v1.min.js".

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: Not exactly @ZedTux, I found a different API for React Native for that particular library, but I did not find a solution to the question as asked.